# Serving SVG as JPEG using Imagick and PHP

Tags: php, xml, svg, imagemagick, imagick

I have an SVG string that I want to serve as JPEG using PHP. For this (and a lot more things) I am using Imagick. Below is the code from PHP:

```
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="28.125px" height="28.125px" viewBox="0 0 28.125 28.125" style="enable-background:new 0 0 28.125 28.125;" xml:space="preserve" background="transparent"><g><g><path d="M14.063,0L1.659,6.617v0.464c0,13.979,11.906,20.767,12.026,20.834l0.378,0.21l0.377-0.21   c0.12-0.067,12.026-6.854,12.026-20.834V6.617L14.063,0z M14.063,26.329C12.13,25.096,3.445,18.92,3.214,7.544l10.849-5.787 l10.849,5.786C24.681,18.919,15.996,25.094,14.063,26.329z"/><path d="M4.004,8.001c0.416,10.17,7.652,15.812,10.059,17.412c2.407-1.601,9.643-7.241,10.059-17.411L14.063,2.636L4.004,8.001z M14,21.191c-1.067,0-1.778-0.771-1.778-1.799c0-1.047,0.731-1.799,1.778-1.799c1.048,0,1.739,0.752,1.759,1.799 C15.759,20.421,15.067,21.191,14,21.191z M15.127,16.605h-2.253l-0.456-8.954h3.144L15.127,16.605z"/></g></g></svg>';
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $image;
```

The problem here is that I get the following error when executed:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/358' in C:\xampp\htdocs\univar\build\makesprite.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\univar\build\makesprite.php(10): Imagick->readimageblob('<?xml version="...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\univar\build\makesprite.php on line 10
```

I am clueless as to what is happening. I tried reading a SVG file as well but to no success. Can someone please help?

Comment: Using Image magick v6.9 on windows and installed the imagick dll for the same in xampp/php and added the dll ref to php.ini

Comment: Double check how your referencing the dll's in xampp/php. Looks like `CORE_RL_librsvg_.dll` can't be found/loaded by `Imagick`

Comment: @emcconville I dont see that dll in the package i downloaded from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows . That is why it is missing. Where can i find all the required dll's?

Comment: @emcconville Thanks a lot!! That was a great help! I figured out the other stuff already.

Comment: If you figured out what was wrong, you should write down in an answer of your own what exactly you did to fix it and mark it as "Accepted". This will help future readers of this question who experience the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a combination that works. After a bit of struggle, I was finally able to get the below combination to work on my machine.

OS: Windows 7 64 Bit
PHP: 5.5.6
XAMPP: 1.8.3
    Compiler: MSVC11
    Architecture: x86
ImageMagick: ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll (available [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/))
Imagick DLL: PHP5.5.x version from http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/

**Note:** After I tried this, Apache started without any error messages. I do have ImageMagick installed in a directory that has no spaces in the name (as some have suggested that might be a problem with some installs). In my case, I installed it to C:\imagemagick.